# Ejecutar comando ssh en un servidor remoto

Tags: java, ssh, ant

Estoy trabajando en un Ant para pasar ficheros a un servidor remoto y eso me funciona bien pero, a la hora de ejecutar un .bat que esta en el servidor remoto para organizar todos los ficheros que paso, no sé cuál es el problema para que, en vez de ejecutar exec en el servidor remoto, lo haga en local.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```xml
<sshsession
    host="xxxxxxxxxx" 
    port="22" 
    trust="true"
    username="Administrator" 
    password="xxxxxxxx">

    <sequential>

        <exec executable="C:/tools_deploy/extractor.bat" spawn="true">
            <arg value="C:/tools_deploy/extractor.bat"/>
        </exec>

    </sequential>
</sshsession>
```

Esto lo hago mediante SSHSession y no sé cuál puede ser el error.

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que estás intentando conectarte con SSH al propio servidor local? ¿Sabes si está instalado el servicio SSH?

Comment: No. Estoy intentando ejecutar un .bat que esta en un servidor remoto mediante un comando de consola a través de un Ant en java.

Comment: Perdona que insista pero no estoy seguro de lo que preguntas... ¿quieres decir que lo que no sabes es como pasar los comandos que se deben ejecutar a través de la sesión ssh?

Comment: Eso es. Estoy intentando pasar y ejecutar comandos y el código que estoy utilizando me lo ejecuta en local y  no en el servidor remoto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya e conseguido hacer lo que quería.
Básicamente en vez de usar el sshsession e usado el sshexec (ya que solo quiero ejecutar un comando).

El código resultante es este:

```
<sshexec 
    host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" 
    port="22" 
    **trust="true"**
    username="mi_usuario" 
    password="secreta" command="C:/tools_deploy/extractor.bat">
</sshexec>
```

Cuidado: si no pones el **trust** da fallo cuando lo ejecutas.

De todas formas gracias por vuestro tiempo.
Un saludo.

Comment: Enhorabuena por haberlo encontrado, y gracias por poner tu solución para ayudar a otros que tengan el problema. Pasados un par de días podrás marcar tu propia respuesta como correcta, y será más fácil que gente con el mismo problema encuentre tu solución.